# When using a Restlet in SuiteScript to create a record, why is the 'createdFrom' field not being saved with the expected value?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am utilizing the code snippet below to assign a value to the 'otherrefnum' field while creating a 'Return Authorization' record to establish a relationship with a sales order:

```
  returnAuthRecord.setValue({
    fieldId: "createdfrom", value: 1,
  });
```

However, despite setting the value using this code, the 'otherrefnum' field is not saving the expected value. What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe setting the created from field will source in the data from the transaction.

Look at using record.transform

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion, resolved my question.